# 404 Page not found error when I try to access Custom module in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

My customer model reposites is In https://github.com/aloha1003/magento-question

I put DemoMod dir  in /app/code/local

and execute 
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cahce:flush

But open browser on http://localhost/magento/demo/index/index

And got 404 page not found error.

How could I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong folder and file path, follow below code with proper file path.

> app/code/Demo/Mod/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Mod\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Customer login form page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        echo 'Hello World';
        exit;
    }


}
```

> app/code/Demo/Mod/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="demo" frontName="demo">
            <module name="Demo_Mod" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Demo/Mod/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_Mod" setup_version="2.1.1" active="true"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Demo/Mod/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_Mod',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Setup upgrade**, **deploy static content**, **cache clean** after complete above code.